# PHP Date in MYSQL Date_Format

Tags: php, mysql, date, mysqli, date-format

I want to get the profit of my website for the other month (January) and I don't know how. Here is what I tried to do, but it doesn't work:

```
$lastm = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month', time()));

$lmonth = "SELECT SUM(profit) as lp FROM statistics WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m') = DATE_FORMAT($lastm,'%m')";

$lmonthp = $mydb -> query($lmonth);

$lmp = $lmonthp -> fetch_assoc();

$lmonthprofit = $lmp["lp"];
```

It only works if I put NOW() instead of $lastm in the mysql query (that's profit for current month).

Comment: You can replace your first line with `$lastm = date('Y-m-d');` the rest is unnecessary.

Comment: @JohnConde so how it would show me the profit from January if $lastm = 2014-02-26?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MONTH(`column_with_date_format`) function to get the month of that date

```
$lmonth = "SELECT SUM(profit) as lp FROM statistics WHERE `date` = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Also. date is a reserved keyword so you have to put those quotes around it

MONTH() function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: I would have solved if it was so easy. But I want to show the profit from the last month (ex: if today is 15 June, I want that $lmonthprofit will show the profit from May and so on). I said that I want to show profit from January to be more easy to understand. So it automatically change, not needed to edit it every month.

Comment: @user1330335 sorry, missed a bit, try now, did that work?

Comment: yes man, thank you very much, just needed to put MONTH(date)..

Comment: @user1330335 Perfect :), if you can accept that'd be great!